# Error in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : (converted from warning) unknown timezone 'GMT'

Tags: r, lubridate

I find myself confronted with a problem for which I fail to find a clue to a solution - which makes it very hard to actually deal with it.. Here goes: In R (with R-Studio) I try to create a Date object with the library `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
ymd(20161001)
```

which results in an error:

> Error in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : 
>         (converted from warning) unknown timezone 'GMT'

A second run (and any subsequent runs) of the last command yields the correct result:

```
ymd(20161001)
[1] "2016-01-01"
```

until I restart my R-session, when again the first run triggers an error. I've checked several settings, but can't find anything *changing* from the first to the second run. Here's, for instance, the output of my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.6.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5  tools_3.3.2   stringi_1.1.2 stringr_1.1.0
```

`Sys.timezone()` says `[1] "Europe/Berlin"`, and `Sys.getenv('TZ')` is empty: `""`

I do find others stumbling upon the same warning, such as [this blogpost](https://www.r-bloggers.com/doing-away-with-%E2%80%9Cunknown-timezone%E2%80%9D-warnings/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749040/as-posixct-produces-unknown-timezone-error-after-mavericks-and-r-upgrade-in-ma), but these problems have to do with *times*, whereas I would prefer to ignore times altogether, and deal with *dates* only.

Comment: try:
`Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","English")`

Comment: Tnx, but unfortunately that did not work out. Behaviour remains the same.

Comment: @Taeke have you found a solution?  I am experiencing the same issue with ymd_hms - first call throws the same error, the second call executes perfectly fine.

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet. If you do find a solution, I'd be glad to hear of it! Sorry for the late response..

Comment: You could try `anytime::anydate(20161001)` which works just fine. `Date` objects do not have timezones so the error really should not occur in the first place...

Comment: I had exactly the same problem with the lubridate package. After setting my systime `Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT')` I added *tz="GMT"* to dmy `dmy(pulver420w$Date ,tz="GMT")` and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error today. My code was in an Rmarkdown file set to output as a tufte_html document. I was loading the following packages:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(extrafont)
library(extrafontdb)
library(tufte)
```

To get my code working I did the following:
First, I got off my company's VPN, suspecting that maybe it was the problem, but I was still getting the error when using my home wifi and no VPN. Next, I updated all my packages but was still getting the error.
Then, I shut down my Macbook and rebooted but was still getting the error.
Finally, I changed my script to no longer load tidyverse as a whole but instead load:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(extrafont)
library(extrafontdb)
library(tufte)
```

Then my Rmarkdown file rendered to html without the unknown timezone error. Unfortunately, I cannot pinpoint what exactly fixed the error or why loading parts but not the whole tidyverse seemed to do the trick for me. Did you ever solve your problem?

---

My session info when it worked:

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tufte_0.2       extrafontdb_1.0 extrafont_0.17  stringr_1.2.0  
[5] readr_1.1.1     dplyr_0.7.4     tibble_1.3.4    lubridate_1.7.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.13     Rttf2pt1_1.3.4   knitr_1.17       bindr_0.1       
 [5] magrittr_1.5     hms_0.3          R6_2.2.2         rlang_0.1.4     
 [9] tools_3.4.2      htmltools_0.3.6  yaml_2.1.14      rprojroot_1.2   
[13] digest_0.6.12    assertthat_0.2.0 bindrcpp_0.2     glue_1.2.0      
[17] evaluate_0.10.1  rmarkdown_1.8    stringi_1.1.6    compiler_3.4.2  
[21] backports_1.1.1  pkgconfig_2.0.1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not yet solved this problem. Your solution (or should I call it a work-around?) seems rather bizarre to me. I cannot get it to work either; I get the error anyway, whether I load lubridate before the tidyverse, after it, with it, or without it. Seems not to make a difference on my system.

As with you, I'm receiving this error on my company's laptop. In the meantime, I did receive a new laptop with updated R / packages. Did not change this behaviour though..

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314121/r-error-unknown-timezone-with-as-posixct) worked for me.

I added `Sys.setenv(TZ='America/Detroit')` to my script, for example.

Comment: I checked with my system, and indeed there is no TZ environment variable available. Unfortunately, setting it does not change the observed behaviour - still getting an `error()`

Answer (score 0):

The solution presented here [R error: unknown timezone with as.POSIXct()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314121/r-error-unknown-timezone-with-as-posixct)

In my case, after including Sys.setenv(TZ="America/Lima") at the beginning of the code everything works fine.
Please check the list of valid TZ values at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones