# How do I set my timezone to pacific standard time?

Tags: r, timezone

Noob question - I'm trying to set my timezone to PST but keep getting unknown timezone warnings. My macbook's timezone is set but isn't communicating with R and R doesn't seem to like my request for PST. I'm sure this is an easy fix but can't seem to find any solutions that have worked yet. Thanks in advance!

[Script/console showing warning message: unknown timezone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGgK2.png)

Comment: Try `Sys.setenv(TZ="America/Los_Angeles")`

Comment: Please show the code & error as text rather than an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a potential answer on the R-bloggers website [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/doing-away-with-%E2%80%9Cunknown-timezone%E2%80%9D-warnings/).

It combines the above comment: `Sys.setenv(TZ="America/Los_Angeles")`
with some background info on the problem.

Also, see this question on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515551/r-timezone-warning-on-mac).

The answer basically states that anything less than version R 3.4.3 will not get along with MacOS 10.13 'High Sierra' for timezones.

So check with...

```
 R.version[names(R.version) == "version.string"] #OR
 sessionInfo()$R.version$version.string #and if it's less than 3.4.3,
```

## download the latest R version here: https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/

## This should fix it.