# installing lightgbm_r on a mac timezone error occurs

Tags: r, macos, lightgbm

following code to install lightgbm with terminal on a mac delivers the error below.

```
R CMD INSTALL --build . --no-multiarch
```

error:

```
mac_computer:lightgbm_r user1$ R CMD INSTALL --build . --no-multiarch
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library’
* installing *source* package ‘lightgbm’ ...
Warnung in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz)
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018i.1.0/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin'
** libs
installing via 'install.libs.R' to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/lightgbm
Fehler in eval(ei, envir) : Cannot find lib_lightgbm.so
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/lightgbm’
```

Has anyone an idea how to solve it?

Comment: You can check [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1852) issue on github

Comment: i checked the description on github but thats not about timezone issue

Comment: In your message, it also says `Cannot find lib_lightgbm.so`

Comment: For time zone errors, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314121/r-error-unknown-timezone-with-as-posixct)