# POSIXct stopped working and cannot update timezone

Tags: r, posixct

I am trying to subset dates, such as here:

```
  df <- data.frame(
    paste0("ID", rep(1:5)),  
    c("8/1/2019", "9/1/2019", "10/1/2019", "11/1/2019", "12/1/2019"))

  names(df) <- c("ID", "dates")

  df[as.POSIXct(strptime(df$dates, "%m/%d/%Y")) <
     as.POSIXct("10/1/2019", "%m/%d/%Y"), ]
```

But I get the following warnings:

```
    1: In strptime(xx, f, tz = tz) : unknown timezone '%m/%d/%Y'
    2: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone '%m/%d/%Y'
```

I ran these commands regularly in the past and not had this issue till now. It started on December 31st, so possibly the new year/new decade is the cause, but I am not certain.

I tried setting the timezone manually as recommended [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314121/r-error-unknown-timezone-with-as-posixct?rq=1), I also updated from v. 3.5.3 to 3.6.2. Neither fixed the issue.

Any insight into what's going on here?

Comment: Have you tried this? `df[as.POSIXct(strptime(df$dates, "%m/%d/%Y"), tz = "America/Chicago") <
       as.POSIXct("10/1/2019", "%m/%d/%Y", tz = "America/Chicago"), ]`

Comment: Avoid the whole timezone concern and just use `as.Date()`

Comment: @TheSciGuy I had tried df[as.POSIXct(strptime(df$dates, "%m/%d/%Y", tz = "America/Chicago")) but the argument "tz =" was within the parentheses so it didn't work.

Comment: @Dave2e, that worked as well, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last line, you have

```
as.POSIXct("10/1/2019", "%m/%d/%Y")
```

The arguments to `as.POSIXct` are `(x, tz, ...)`.  To specify a format, you need to name it, i.e.

```
df[as.POSIXct(strptime(df$dates, "%m/%d/%Y")) <
   as.POSIXct("10/1/2019", format = "%m/%d/%Y"), ]
```

or even better,

```
df[as.POSIXct(df$dates, format = "%m/%d/%Y") <
   as.POSIXct("10/1/2019", format = "%m/%d/%Y"), ]
```